# C# MultiProject TemplateWizard генерация проекта в папку SolutionFolder

Tags: c#, шаблоны, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Разрабатываю TemplateWizard для генерации решений из нескольких проектов в VS.

Приложение построено по следующей логике:

1)Запуск IWizard из шаблона в Visual Studio.

2)В приложении происходит настройка будущего проекта.

3)В соответствии с настройкой решения приложение дергает уже другой шаблон запуска командой `myDTE.LaunchWizard(vsTemplatePath, ref contextParams);`

3)Шаблон в свою очередь запускает ещё один(другой) IWizard для генерации шаблонов проектов и добавления их в решение.

**Проблема:**
Все проекты сгенерированные таким образом генерируются в корень Решения.

**Как генерировать проект командой `myDTE.LaunchWizard(vsTemplatePath, ref contextParams);` в логическую папку решения (SolutionFolder)?**

(Могу предоставить необходимые участки кода и информацию по запросу)

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что программно это вряд ли получится сделать. Вот если менять в файле `.vstemplate` значения элемента `<SolutionFolder...` - то тогда получится. Вот ссылка на описание: [SolutionFolder Element (Visual Studio Templates)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171399.aspx)

Comment: @DenisBubnov мой TemplateWizard генерирует ряд проектов в зависимости от выбранной конфигурации решения. Я не могу задать фиксированное количество проектов в ProjectCollection. Так-же есть ещё один вопрос, ответ на который меня тоже устроит: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603829/c-envdte-%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Видимо я что-то не так понял, ну, посмотрим, может быть дадут хороший ответ