# C# EnvDTE Перемещение проектов внутри решения

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Необходимо переместить проект из решения в папку решения программно. Пытался удалять проект из решения и добавлять его снова в папку с помощью `EnvDTE` `SolutionFolder.AddFromFile(string filePath);` т.к. не нашёл в документации функции перемещения проекта по решению(или установки нового родителя). И всё казалось-бы работает так-как нужно, однако при добавлении проектов таким образом на Start Page в Колонке быстрого доступа появляются проекты добавленные в решение.

**Как переместить проект внутри решения не передобавляя проект(не засоряя панель быстрого запуска)?**

Функция добавления как она есть на данный момент:

```
protected Project AddProjectToSolutionFolder(Project project1, SolFolderTypes solutionFolderType)
{
    try
    {
        Solution2 solution = (Solution2)((DTE2)base._dteObject).Solution;

        string projFullname = project1.FullName;

        string solutionFolderName = solutionFolderType == SolFolderTypes.Folder1 ? "Folder1" : "Folder2";

        Project project = GetSolutionSubFolder(solution, solutionFolderName);

        if (project != null)
        {
            SolutionFolder folder = (SolutionFolder)project.Object;
            solution.Remove(project1);
            project1 = folder.AddFromFile(projFullname);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return project1;
}

private static Project GetSolutionSubFolder(Solution2 solution, string subfolder)
{
    Projects projects = solution.Projects;
    Project folder = projects.Cast<Project>().FirstOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.Name, subfolder));

    if (folder == null)
        folder = solution.AddSolutionFolder(subfolder);

    return folder;
}
```